# Can write MyBatis mapping annotation on the Bean

Tags: mybatis

In MyBatis, should use like this, it is too much code and it looks very inelegant:

```java
@Mapper
public interface SeqMapper {

    @Select("select * FROM COMMON_SEQ WHERE APP_CODE = #{appCode} FOR UPDATE")
    @Results(id = "seqDOMap", value = {
            @Result(column = "APP_CODE", property = "appCode"),
            @Result(column = "SEQ", property = "seq"),
            @Result(column = "STEP", property = "step"),
            @Result(column = "SEQ_MAX", property = "seqMax"),
            @Result(column = "UPDATED_TIME", property = "updatedTime"),
            @Result(column = "BEFORE_UPDATED_TIME", property = "beforeUpdatedTime"),
            @Result(column = "RESET_TIME", property = "resetTime"),
    })
    SeqDO selectForUpdate(SeqDO seqDO);
```

```java
public class SeqDO {
    private Integer appCode;
    private Long seq;
    private Long step;
    private Long seqMax;
    private Date updatedTime;
    private Date beforeUpdatedTime;
    private Date resetTime;
```

I would use like this, concise and beautiful:

```java
public class SeqDO {

    @Result("APP_CODE")
    private Integer appCode;

    @Result("SEQ")
    private Long seq;

    @Result("STEP")
    private Long step;

    @Result("SEQ_MAX")
    private Long seqMax;

    @Result("UPDATED_TIME")
    private Date updatedTime;

    @Result("BEFORE_UPDATED_TIME")
    private Date beforeUpdatedTime;

    @Result("RESET_TIME")
    private Date resetTime;
```

My friend said that "as" can be used, so that it also meets the specification of not using "select *", which is okay.

If can write on the field, please answer.

```java
@Mapper
public interface SeqMapper {

    @Select("select " +
            "APP_CODE as appCode, " +
            "SEQ as seq, " +
            "STEP as step, " +
            "SEQ_MAX as seqMax, " +
            "UPDATED_TIME as updatedTime, " +
            "BEFORE_UPDATED_TIME as beforeUpdatedTime, " +
            "RESET_TIME as resetTime " +
            "FROM COMMON_SEQ WHERE APP_CODE = #{appCode} FOR UPDATE")
    SeqDO selectForUpdate(SeqDO seqDO);
```

(The following text is purely to make up the word count :)

I think there is too much code in xml, so I want to use annotations, and the annotations can be easily jumped in the IDE.
If the way is like the following, the jump will be more convenient, and the field name does not need to be modified again.

Answer (score 0):

My My friend said that can use mybatis plus:

https://baomidou.com/en/guide/annotation.html#tablefield